# Node.js Как сделать получение аргументов

Tags: javascript, node.js

Я пишу бота на Дискорд, но не могу понять, как сделать прием аргументов, типа пользователь вводит "!отправить коины (кол-во) (uid)". Как получить эти аргументы? Я пытался обнаруживать пробелы, но как-то не вышло. Есть ли какая нибудь библиотека?

Comment: с помощью regex -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression

Comment: discord.js - документация, там очень много инфы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\(([^\)]+)\)` - вот такое регулярное выражение подойдет. Открывающая скобка, любой символ, кроме закрывающей скобки, закрывающая скобка + то, что внутри выделяем в отдельную группу.

```js
const matchRegExp = /\(([^\)]+)\)/gm;

const testString = '!отправить коины (4) (uid)';

const result = [];
let match;
while(match = matchRegExp.exec(testString)) {
  result.push(match[1]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Пойду читать руководство по этим выражениям, чтобы сделать без скобок :)